# Tabulator: Horizontal Scrollbar and Calculation Row

Tags: tabulator

I'm curious if the horizontal scrollbar is always placed between the table and the calculations row as seen in the sreen-shot below or, is there a way to place it after the calculations row that I am just not finding?

[Tabulator Scrollbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W7AGt.png)

I've searched the web and Tabulator documentation but couldn't find any additional information.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to change this behaviour, the calculation row sits in the static footer of the table, not in the scrollable area of the virtual DOM